# Do you have to know php to build a wordpress blog theme?

Tags: wordpress-theming

I want to build my own theme for my wordpress blog. Nothing fancy, just a custom background, a few images , posts and comentaries.

Do I have to know php to do that?

Can you direct me to a good tutorial on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you need to know at least basic php (the loops, variables etc). You will required it at the time of theme creation and content fetching from admin.

Answer (score 0):

You should start with a good [PHP tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/). Once you understand PHP, the [Wordpress documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/) has tons of useful resources.